# Empty lines when generate a jasper reports 6.11

Tags: jasper-reports

[image: attached the report content and I am blocked ho wto remove the blanks between ligne1 and ligne2]

I am trying to generate a PDF with **JasperReports 6.11**; But i have got so empty lines . I have try this option : isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" but it does not help , it removes the empty fields

have you any idea about it please ?

Comment: any suggestion please ?

Comment: Why not to remove the lines in the query WHERE clause?

Comment: I'am just adding a list of data and I have verify that there are no empty lines on the query . I have alwayes  the empty line on the report

Comment: Without posting your jrxml file It's hard to evaluate